# Extracting Data Relating To Reminders Snoozed

Tags: vba, outlook

I have no VBA knowledge but am on a passage of learning. I have obtained the following coding from a public source (Diane Peremsky) of outlook forums. It has a bug I am working on to resolve and strangely returns different data on successive iterations.

Could somebody try provide (or guide me) to add the first 3 lines of the message body to which it refers?

```
Sub SnoozedReminders()

  Dim oReminder As Reminder
  Dim oReminders  As Outlook.Reminders
  Dim RemItems As String

  Set oReminders = Outlook.Reminders
  For Each oReminder In oReminders

  If (oReminder.OriginalReminderDate <> oReminder.NextReminderDate) Then
    RemItems = RemItems & oReminder.Caption & vbCrLf & _
    "Original Reminder time: " & oReminder.OriginalReminderDate & vbCrLf & _ 
    "Snoozed to: " & oReminder.NextReminderDate & vbCrLf _
    & vbCrLf
  End If

  Next oReminder

  Set oMail = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
  oMail.Subject = "Generated on " & Now
  oMail.Body = RemItems
  oMail.Display

  End Sub
```

Comment: I think the `oReminder.Item` property refers to the object linked to the reminder - see here for how to determine what type of object it is: https://www.slipstick.com/developer/send-email-outlook-reminders-fires/#:~:text=Send%20a%20message%20to%20yourself%20when%20a%20reminder%20fires

Comment: Thank you to all responders .I have gotten more knowledge and have a solution.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The [Reminder.Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.reminder.item) property returns a corresponding Outlook item. So, you may get the message body from there.

```
Sub SnoozedReminders()

  Dim oReminder As Reminder
  Dim oReminders  As Outlook.Reminders
  Dim RemItems As String

Set oReminders = Outlook.Reminders
  For Each oReminder In oReminders

  If (oReminder.OriginalReminderDate <> oReminder.NextReminderDate) Then
   RemItems = RemItems & oReminder.Caption & vbCrLf & "Original Reminder time: " & 
oReminder.OriginalReminderDate & vbCrLf & "Snoozed to: " & oReminder.NextReminderDate & vbCrLf 
& vbCrLf
  End If

  MsgBox oReminder.Item.Body

  Next oReminder
  ...
End Sub
```

The Outlook object model provides three main ways for working with item bodies:

1. [Body](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865304(v=office.15).aspx).
2. [HTMLBody](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868941(v=office.15).aspx).
3. The Word editor. The [WordEditor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868196(v=office.15).aspx) property of the `Inspector` class returns an instance of the Word `Document` which represents the message body.

See [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012%28v=office.12%29.aspx) for more information.